# Gurobi error 10020: Q matrix is not positive semi-definite (PSD)

Tags: java, optimization, matrix, gurobi

I am trying to solve a qudratic programming problem in Java. I wanted to do it using the Gurobi library. This library has an ability to solve problems with quadratic constraints:

[image]

Unfortunately, one of the constraints keeps giving me an error:

Gurobi error 10020: Q matrix is not positive semi-definite (PSD)

So my question is - do you know any way to make the Q matrix positive semi-definite? Or maybe you know any other Java library which could handle this problem?

Comment: It is difficult to answer the question in the stated generality. Quadratic programming problems are not easy. It is often advisable to linearise the problem by introducing additional constraints or variables.

Comment: Could be that you're trying to solve a problem which cannot be cast a a convex quadratic constraints, such as x^Tx >=1. If your lack of positive semidefiniteness simply is due to numerical errors, you can add a small diagonal perturbation on Q, i.e, replace Q with Q + eps*I